# Object variable and Object syntax

Tags: objective-c

if I have the following in my main file

```
int main ( int argc, const char * argv[])
    {
        @autoreleasepool
        {
            Complex * c1 = [[Complex alloc] init];
            Complex * c2 = [[Complex alloc] init];

            Complex * compResult;

            compResult = [c1 add: c2]; 
            [compResult print];
        {

         return0;        

    {

/**implementation of add method **/
-(Complex *) add: (Complex *) f
{
    Complex *result = [[Complex alloc] init]
    result.real = real + f.real;
    result.imaginary = imaginary + f.imaginary;
    return result;
}
```

I know that c1 and c2 are objects, but is compResult considered a variable until we do 
compResult = [c1 add: c2];

My assumption here is that the add method returns an Object and by doing compResult = [c1 add: c2];  we are setting compResult equal to that object.  So does that turn compResult into an object?

So in my mind compResult is a variable that receives the result of the [c1 add: c2], but when we do [compResult print], I get really confused because i thought you can only use this syntax when sending a message (in this case print) to an object?

I guess my main question is after we do compResult =  [c1 add: c2]; is the variable compResult holding/representing an object or does it actually become the object????

Comment: It looks like you have some serious confusion about objects and pointers.  You might want to check out some beginner tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm reading a beginners tutorial right now, so I guess I haven't reached the pointers section yet.  Your answer really clarifies everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`c1` and `c2` are not objects, they're pointers to objects.  Similarly, `compResult` is also a pointer, but at the time of its declaration it's uninitialized, meaning it doesn't point to any specific object.

When you invoke the `add:` method via `[c1 add:c2]`, a new object is created and a pointer to it is returned.  That pointer is assigned to `compResult`.  `compResult` is still just a pointer, exactly like `c1` and `c2`, but now it points to this newly created object, meaning you can send messages to that object (like `[compResult print]`) just like you did with `[c1 add:c2]` before.

Editorial note:  it would be more idiomatic to return an autoreleased object from `add:` rather than the retained one you're using right now.

Answer (score 1):

Neither `c1` nor `c2` are objects - both of them are references to objects <sup>*</sup>, as indicated by the asterisk in their declarations. The difference between them and `compResult` is that they both are initialized at the time they are declared, while `compResult` is initially uninitialized.

After the assignment `compResult` holds a reference to the object allocated inside the `add` method. Under ARC, the variable is considered `__strong` by default, meaning that the result object will be released when `compResult` goes out of scope.

---

<sup>*</sup> Technically, `c1` and `c2` are pointers, but since in ARC-enabled code they acquire special powers to retain and release the objects to which they point, I called them "object references".